# MVC views: How to render a table in a view only when a button clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, search-engine

I am new at MVC and have a view that has a search text box + button a navigation tab and table.

I would like the table to be populated only when the search criteria is entered and the button clicked.

The problem I am having now is that the table section of the view is rendered and returns a null object reference error when the page is loaded.

Other than using jquery/java functions how can I get the table to only populate when the the search criteria is entered and the button clicked?

Do I need to create 2 separate views(one with the table and one without)?

Here are parts of my view:

```
        <div class="searchBox">

              <label>Please search here
                        <input type="text" name="searchTerm" id="searchTerm" value="<%= !string.IsNullOrEmpty((string) ViewData["SearchTerm"]) ? Html.Encode(ViewData["SearchTerm"]) : "" %>" />
                        <input type="button" value="Add" />
                </label>
        </div>

        <ul class="navigation">
    <li><a class="selected" href="#name" >Person1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#dob">Person2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#address">Person3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#status">Person4</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tabSection">
    <div class="basic">


        <table id="person" class="gridview">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>name</th>
                    <th>dob</th>
                    <th>address</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><%= Model.name %></td>
                    <td><%= Model.dob%></td>
                    <td><%= Model.address%></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're somewhat doing it already.  You can just wrap whatever part of your view into a string is not null or empty checking your search term.  Totally unrelated, but a pet peeve of mine is referring to javascript as java.  Java is something else entirely.

Answer (score 2):

You should just wrap your table in this:

```
@if (Model != null)
{
    // table code
}
```

Also, you might want to consider putting your table logic into a partial view, and have the if statement in the partial view. That way, in your main view you could just have `Html.RenderPartial("PARTAILVIEWNAME");` Doing it this way would allow you to have the same table in as many views as you want without having to remember to wrap the table in an if statement every time.